# How to combine the two stock chart,means one chart's Low is equal other chart's High?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Now I can draw the two stock chart in kendo-UI using stock chart,I want to conbine two charts together,Can kendo-UI stock chart achieve this effect?It means the  one chart's Low is equal other chart's High,and the two chart are in the same day?the link is [code demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/whoamiwho/Ra5KW/)My code is here:`

```
    $("#stock-chart").kendoStockChart({
        dataSource: {
            data: [
                {
                    "Date": "01/01/2012 00:10:00",
                    "Open": 60,
                    "High": 100,
                    "Low": 60,
                    "Close": 60,
                    "Volume": 233
                },
                {
                    "Date": "01/01/2012 00:11:00",
                    "Open": 200,
                    "High": 200,
                    "Low": 100,
                    "Close": 200,
                    "Volume": 2333
                }
            ]
        },
        series: [{
            type: "candlestick",
            openField: "Open",
            highField: "High",
            lowField: "Low",
            closeField: "Close"
        }],
        dateField: "Date"
    });
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that because a stock chart  can only have a state at a certain time.